# how to exclude sentences containing specific word

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I m reading a sentence from excel(containing bio data) file and want to extract the organizations where they are working. The file also contains sentences which specifies where the person is studying.
ex :

- i m studying in 'x' instition(university)
- i m student in 'y' college

i want to skip these type of sentences.

I am using regular expression to match these sentences, and if its related to student then skip the part, and only other lines i want write in a separate excel file.

my code is as below..

csvdata = pandas.read_csv("filename.csv",",");
    for data in csvdata:

```
        regEX=re.compile('|'.join([r'\bstudent\b',r'\bstudy[ing]\b']),re.I)
        matched_data=re.match(regEX,data)   
        if matched_data is not None:
            continue

        else:
            ## write the sentence to excel
```

But, when i check the newly created excel file, it still contains the sentences that contain 'student', 'study'.
How regular expression can be modified to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things here:

1) Use `re.search` (`re.match` only searches at the string start)
 2) The regex should be `regEX=re.compile(r"\b(?:{})\b".format('|'.join([r'student',r'study(?:ing)?'])),re.I)`

The `[ing]` only matches 1 symbol, either `i`, `n` or `g` while you intended to match an *optional* `ing` ending. A non-capturing group with a `?` quantifier - `(?:ing)?` - is actually matching 1 or 0 sequences of `ing`s.

Also, `\b(x|y)\b` is a more efficient pattern than `\bx\b|\by\b`, as it involves fewer backtracking steps.

Here is just [a demo](https://ideone.com/CGHf82) of what this regex looks like:

```
import re
pat = r"\b(?:{})\b".format('|'.join([r'student',r'study(?:ing)?']))
print(pat)
# => \b(?:student|study(?:ing)?)\b
regEX=re.compile(pat,re.I)
s = "He is studying here."
mObj = regEX.search(s)
if mObj: 
    print(mObj.group(0))
# => studying
```

Comment: I don't use python and don't know how string `format`works, but `\b{}\b` looks strange. Is it correct?

Comment: @ClasG: Empty `{}` in the `format` method [*Implicitly references the first positional argument*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: OK. But that would mean it expands to `\bstudent|study(?:ing)\b` allowing, for example, "studentdorm" and "chemistrystudy". (I know you don't tie words together like that in English, but...) Might what OP wants, but not what the example code implies. Again, don't speak python, but could it be "corrected" by changing the `'|'` to `'\b|\b'`?

Comment: That is a demo issue, in the explanation, I have the parentheses. I updated the code in the answer now.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).